# Error: Cast System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to query my EF Model (using ASP.NET MVC WebApi) but only the first version (using SingleOrDefault) works and not the second one and i can't get my head around it!

Working:

```
Public Overloads Shared Function GetById(id As Integer) As MEDIA
    Dim db As New EFEntities()
    Dim r As New MEDIA()
    r = db.MEDIA.SingleOrDefault(Function(p) p.id = id)

    Return r
End Function
```

Not Working:

**Error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Data.MEDIA]' to type 'Data.MEDIA'**

```
Public Overloads Shared Function GetById(id As Integer) As MEDIA
    Dim db As New EFEntities()
    r = From media In db.MEDIA
            Where media.id= id _
            Select media

    Return r
End Function
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody could show me how to get the **second version** running and explain what the problem is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, the line:

```
r = db.MEDIA.SingleOrDefault(Function(p) p.id = id)
```

initializes a single MEDIA object.

In your second example, however, the line:

```
r = From media In db.MEDIA
        Where media.id= id _
        Select media
```

initializes a collection of MEDIA objects - incompatible types.

If you changed your return expression in your second example to:

```
Return r.SingleOrDefault()
```

and stick `Dim` in front of the initialization of `r` it'll work.

Comment: I noticed that you haven't declared r. Assuming you are running with Option Explicit Off, it still won't work until you declare r by sticking Dim in front of it or you'll get a MissingMemberException.

Comment: And what would i need to use if the query would select specific columns like: `Select New With { .COLUMNNAME = media.COLUMNNAME }` to use the same function and return AS MEDIA?

Comment: If you want to return that anonymous object from the function, you'd have to change the function type to Object. Then as long as you have Option Strict Off (the default for VB.Net projects), you'd be able to access the COLUMNNAME property without any compile issues.